# How to get xml post request parameters in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a very simple Sinatra app which only does log out the params in the action, and then I use curl to send post data in xml format, but sinatra didn't get the xml parsed:

```
echo '<something>tyrael tong</something>' | curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' -d @- http://localhost:9528/status/update
```

I searched through google with no solution to this. Am I suppose to parse the xml post data by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, content type is just a hint for a server how to handle it. If your server can receive say XML or JSON, content type can tell you how to parse it.

Comment: Yes, but, as a web application framework, like Rails, usually help you parse that data and put it into "params" automatically. I know that Sinatra is more lightweight than Rails but want to make sure I'm not doing something duplicate others' effort.

Answer (score 3):

try this code
require 'plist'

```
post 'some/route'
 content_type :xml
 value=Plist::parse_xml(request.body)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Find a rack parser: https://github.com/achiu/rack-parser which could do the job I want: parse the post body into parameter.

P.S. And need to set the content type to "application/xml"

Comment: Rails uses the middleware use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser to do this parsing. You can use that as well if you like. It's part of the actionpack gem.

Answer (score 0):

As the body of your post message is an xml it will not be parsed by either rails/sinatra. If you want parsing to be done you will need to change the format of data that you are sending and set the content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Then Sinatra will parse that data and put it into the params hash.

Comment: Then it's very strange, I have a Rails setup and with the same code, "logger.info params" will out put a parsed hash. That's happen on both Rails 3.0 and 3.1.

Comment: You're right in Rails is the content-type is properly set the XML will be parsed into a Hash.

Comment: Rails is big and "full-featured"/"bloated". Sinatra is tiny and "lightweight"/"lacking". Do with it what you will.

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the wrong content type for a POST body containing just XML.  This content type is for HTML form submissions.